# Typescript to handle onsubmit and onchange in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I am trying to use typescript and react properly. Right now I am getting stuck using typescript to handle `onChange` and `onSubmit` events. I dont know what annotations and types to use. I found that in my SignUpForm component, using `any` type will remove the errors but I don't feel as this is best practice.

From [DefinitelyTyped source code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a31a2fe9e8417d47550db09e5f9f50fd09a8e60/types/react/index.d.ts#L2004), I am supposed to use `ChangeEventHandler<T>` to handle `<input>` `onchange` but I don't know what `Type(T)` to use because Visual Studio Code says I cannot use `.currentTarget` or `.target` to retrieve the values I want.

[image]

For my `handleSubmit` method, [I think I am supposed to use `FormEventHandler`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a31a2fe9e8417d47550db09e5f9f50fd09a8e60/types/react/index.d.ts#L1290) but once again, I don't know what type to pass in. My text editor is also telling me I don't have access to `.preventDefault()` as well

[image]

SignUpPage.tsx

```
import React, { FormEventHandler, InputHTMLAttributes, EventHandler } from 'react';
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';

interface IProps {}    
interface IState {}

class SignUpPage extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event: FormEventHandler<>): void =>  {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { value, name} = event.;
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <SignUpForm
        handleSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }
        handleChange={ this.handleChange }
      />
    );
  }
}


export default SignUpPage;
```

SignUpForm.tsx

```
interface IProps {}

const SignUpForm = ({ handleSubmit, handleChange }: { handleSubmit: any, handleChange: any} ): JSX.Element => (
  <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
    <input 
      name="email" 
      type="email"
      onChange={ handleChange }>  
    </input>
  </form>
);

export default SignUpForm;
```

Comment: The subtle error is that you are trying to type the underlying events as handlers. The function itself would be a handler, but the event argument should be ChangeEvent or similar, not ChangeEventHandler.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky So the correct type is `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` and `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`?

Comment: That should work for the input, but form would probably need to be HTMLFormElement or similar

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for the tips! Much appreciated! That did fix the problem! However, my callbacks in my functional component are typed `any` is this proper? As I was learning `typescript` I think I should avoid using `any`

Comment: I feel it’s good practice to avoid using any when possible, I think the function itself would be of type ChangeEventHandler for the change event for example, with or without the generic type. You could try that but I’d have to try it myself to confirm. Basically try using what you originally had but for the type of the respective functions.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yup that worked! I know the question is closed and marked as duplicate but I feel that the part 2 of my question is different than the possible duplicate. If you post an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Sounds good. Happy coding!